# php(2474) malloc: *** mmap(size=1...0) failed (error code=12)

Tags: php, malloc, mmap

I'm writing a php script to run on a terminal, the script starts running, but at some point I get the follow error every time. I have an iMac with Mountain Lion. I using apache and php by system and mysql installed via brew.

```
php(2474) malloc: *** mmap(size=18446744071562072064) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

What could be causing this? How to fix?
thanks

Comment: Refer this : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_myisam_mmap_size

Comment: Find the line where the error is thrown and post the related code.

Comment: @BhavikShah: in my file my.cnf there is no variable `myisam_mmap_size ` :S

Comment: @rekire: I do not think it is a code problem. The same code on another machine works perfectly. I think it's a configuration problem or php or mysql.

Comment: what versions of PHP, mySQL, Apache and other relevant software have you got installed?

Comment: @SDC: PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) - Zend Engine v2.3.0 with Xdebug v2.1.3. Apache/2.2.22 (Unix). MySQL: 5.5.29.

Comment: Refer [this](http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-dev/2008/May/msg00033.html) and [this](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/112785-malloc-error-cant-allocate-region-mac-os-x.html) and check if it can help. Frankly dude, not sure but giving all i got on this issue.

Comment: I found the problem present in php.ini: `xdebug.show_local_vars = 1`. I remove this attr and now i don't have error! ;)